# Change default right click menu color from white to black?

Tags: themes, ambiance

In 12.04 Ambiance theme, the default right click menu color changed from black to white.

From this [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/925895), it appears this decision *is by design*

But I love black only. How can I change it to black?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Reminds me of the time I was [tweaking 11.10's Ambiance to get a dark sidebar in Nautilus](http://askubuntu.com/q/78653/18612). That's not an answer to this question, per se, but editing the theme file(s) like I did is probably the way one would go about this, and it might give someone a place to start for formulating a proper answer. Checking the commit logs for `light-themes` in 12.04 on Launchpad to see when the change was made and a diff of the edits might also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stan Angeloff has created a theme that requires the use of ubuntu-tweak or gnome-tweak-tool (i used the former) to enable. Check this [link](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/AmbianceOneiric):

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Ok here's the modified Ambiance theme for 12.04

[You can download the theme file from my blog](http://solancer.blogspot.in/2012/04/dark-ambiance-theme-for-ubuntu-1204.html)

Extract it in `home/username/.themes/`. Use gnome-tweak-tools to change the theme.

Problem solved ;)

Comment: may i know what's your wallpaper name?

Answer (score 1):

Now I suggest you use deviant-art to find a window theme that looks like Ambiance but has a black right-click menu I was able to find color versions of these themes at this link http://ubuntu-art.org/content/show.php?content=147891 but it will take some work finding an older version of Ambiance with this customization unless the Ubuntu community does something to change it for Precise.

If you have never changed a custom theme follow this [link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-GNOME-Themes-in-Ubuntu-11-10-231213.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

it will definitly work if you edit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css file because all theme colors rendered from that file but to do that you need to be root

`gksu gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Answer (score 1):

As per [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-revert-to-dark-menus-for-ambiance-theme-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

you can use [this](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/AmbianceOneiric/zipball/master) tweaked ambiance for 12.04

> To make use of Ambiance Oneiric hit the button above to download the
>   .zip file. Then extract the .zip archive in to the ‘.themes’ folder in
>   your Home directory (tip: you’ll need to press CTRL+H to reveal hidden
>   files).

Then apply the theme use [myunity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/myunity/)

[image]

[image]

THE RESULT
[image]

**Linked question**

[How to change GTK+ theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93278/how-to-change-gtk-theme)