# White menu colour on Ubuntu 12.04 live boot

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change default right click menu color from white to black?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119123/change-default-right-click-menu-color-from-white-to-black)

I was playing with my new Ubuntu 12.04 by live booting and I found the desktop right click menu has white color, but on the panel it turns black. I remember the last time I was using Ubuntu 11.10 the menu color was black. Is this some kind of 'bug' on the live booting? Problem with contrast I guess?

Comment: @fossfreedom
sorry ,I thought it is not exact duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not problem, It is the new colour scheme of the ambiance theme

Comment: Hmmm.. are you sure?

Comment: Yeah ,there is a similar question in this site itself (to change the colour scheme to old colour scheme)

Comment: lol.. I thought it got something to do with the contrast.. thx anyway