# How can I change nautilus background to a dark color?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the background color/pattern in a Nautilus window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65759/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-pattern-in-a-nautilus-window)

I'd like to know if it was possible to change the background of nautilus to a dark color.

Any ideas ?