# how to change background of nautilus in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, themes, nautilus-actions

As the question goes, How can I change the background of nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 ??

I have already tried `dconf-editor`, `gtk-tweaker`, `gnome-tweaker`. They change the color of some parts of some pannel but not the background of nautilus in icons view.

Comment: As far I know the dconf method does no longer work as of version 3.8 :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can edit the `gtk-main.css` or `nautilus.css` files.

I recommend you to try this under your `~/.themes` and not system-wide. You may either change the background color of nautilus only or the base theme as a whole, which affects a lot more programs. In this example I will change the background color in the default Ubuntu Theme **"Ambiance"** (*in Ubuntu Gnome use the folder Default instead*) from white *(#ffffff)* to a light grey *(#D8D8D8)*. Feel free to pick any other color.

For comparison how it looks like in the beginning:
[image: Natuilus css file]

### Create a copy in `~/`

Create your `~/.themes` directory and copy the original Ambiance theme to it.

```
mkdir ~/.themes
cp -R /usr/share/themes/Ambiance ~/.themes/
```

### Change the background color for the whole theme

If you want to change the base color for the whole theme, edit the base_color *(Hex notation #??????)* in `gtk-main.css`. This changes the background color of other applications (eg: gedit) as well.

```
nano ~/.themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
```

Change this line:

```
@define-color base_color #ffffff;
```

For this one:

```
@define-color base_color #D8D8D8;
```

To save the changes in nano, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**Effect:**
[image: Background color for the whole theme]

### Change the background color for nautlius only

If you want to change the background color for nautilus, edit `nautilus.css`.

```
nano ~/.themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

Add this lines to the beginning of the file.

```
 NautilusWindow * .view {
     background-color: #D8D8D8; 
}
```

[image: Natuilus css file]

To save the changes in nano, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**Effect**

[image: Background color for nautilus only]

To see the changes you can [restart nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/19981/42073), logout login or restart your machine.

Comment: Is there a reference to which I can refer to for further change in theme? (specially nautilus) for example how can I change color of icon text, or the color of the icon when selected, etc.?

Comment: @VahidNateghi: Not exaclty a list, but you can view the structure of the default themes in ubuntu (Ambiance), and here you have a link to a basic gtk3 theming guide http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-1-basics/  and this link is for gnome developer for GtkCssProvider (selector, widget classes) https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkCssProvider.html .hope this helps.

Comment: @VahidNateghi I was able to successfully change the color of the icon text by adding
    color: #FFF;
to the above styles

Comment: In 16.04 the file has been moved to `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`.

Comment: What about changing the color of the side panel?

Answer (score 7):

Roman's solution will work, but actually there's no need to copy the entire Ambiance theme to your `.themes` directory.  Instead, you can simply create a file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and put any changes you want there, such as

```
NautilusWindow * .view {
 background-color: #D8D8D8; 
}
```

Then restart Nautilus.  The definition in your `gtk.css` file will override the theme defaults and you'll see the background color you wanted.

Comment: Is there somewhere where I can see how to change the other parameters? Some kind of list where I could try playing with the hexa-decimal colors? I managed to do your solution but I want to learn how to change the rest of the colors, not just the background one. +1

Comment: What about changing the color of the side panel as well?

Answer (score 3):

Just change the system appearance to dark:

`System -> Appearance -> Dark`

Nautilus will inherit the color scheme.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change colours is to install a theme.

So first install Unity Tweak Tool.

Then create a `~/.themes` folder

Then find and download your preferred theme. [This is an example](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/OMG_Suite?content=149294). Unzip the themes in the folder created.

Open Unity Tweak Tool and under themes choose the one just installed.

Comment: Hmm those do not change the nautilus background.

Comment: Some themes do change the Nautilus background. I'm using [one that does](http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Evolve-GTK3-Theme-264780816).