# Remove black line from (15.04 - Vivid) Files/Nautilus sidebar

Tags: nautilus, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to remove the black line from the sidebar of the latest Ubuntu? It sticks out and always causes me to lose focus when I'm working, because it stands out way too much compared to the rest of the area.

[image]

Comment: This [Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/465968) is related: it explains how to change the background colour of nautilus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve this we will edit `nautilus.css`.

We will do this for the current user and not system-wide.

### Copying your theme to your home folder

Open a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.themes/
cp -R /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/ ~/.themes/
```

*(if you are not using the **Ambiance** theme (default), you will need to adapt the last command)*

### Editing `nautilus.css`

In a terminal open nautilus.css:

```
gedit ~/.themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
```

Add the following lines to the end of the file:

```
NautilusWindow .sidebar .separator,
NautilusWindow .sidebar .view .separator {
   color: shade (@bg_color, 0.95); 
}
```

Save the file.

Log out and in again (or enter `nautilus -q` command in Terminal to restart Nautilus) and you are done.

### Result

[image]

Comment: IT creates another theme by the name Ambience.  Technically this fix requires modifying the GTK Theme. We could apply this even to any other theme. I would rather not make a copy once I test this OK! I would change the GTK theme at its source folder. Anways ! I can confirm that this works !!