# Changing the background color of the File-Manager

Tags: colors, color-management

I have Ubuntu 14.04. The background color of the File-Manager. White is too tiring for my eyes. Is there any way I can change this to something dark, maybe gray or black?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that answer.

Comment: Are you talking about the file manager or about a command line?

Comment: I am talking about file manager. Changing the background color of terminal is trivial.

Comment: @mchid i think it's duplicated here !! http://askubuntu.com/questions/465908/how-to-change-background-of-nautilus-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install a "dark" GTK theme. Many popular ones are Numix, Delorean Dark, Ambience Dark, etc.

My personal favorite is delorean dark and here are instructions for installing that theme:

```
mkdir ~/.themes
cd ~/.themes
wget http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/344/0/4/delorean_dark_theme_3_6_g__vs_2_56_by_killhellokitty-d5nnoxt.zip
unzip delorean_dark_theme_3_6_g__vs_2_56_by_killhellokitty-d5nnoxt.zip
```

You will need a tweak tool such as unity-tweak-tool and or gnome-tweak-tool to apply the theme.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

[See my similar answer here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/563140/167115)