# Lubuntu 18.10 black theme (black background, and white/bright text in every apps including file manager)

Tags: lubuntu, themes, lxqt

```
user@linux:~$ head -2 /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)"
user@linux:~$
```

The default theme in Lubuntu has light themes (Bright and White), though I prefer a dark theme (With greyish and blackish background, and white text) as that kind of theme is good for my eyes (strains less!!).

Therefore, I followed this link https://www.deviantart.com/satya164/art/elementary-Dark-GTK3-Theme-244257862 and tried to install it.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:satyajit-happy/themes
 This PPA contains various themes for Gnome and Xfce.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~satyajit-happy/+archive/ubuntu/themes
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                            
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                 
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                     
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]          
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/satyajit-happy/themes/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install elementary-dark-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elementary-dark-theme
user@linux:~$
```

However, I'm getting the error says that it "Unable to locate package elementary-dark-theme"

I've also tried [Changing the background color of the File-Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790498/changing-the-background-color-of-the-file-manager) but didn't work too.

I would like to get black background and white/bright text on every application including File Manager. Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Lubuntu is on topic here. That ppa doesn't have an 18.10 version. It looks like it stopped being updated with 15.10

You should remove the ppa from your system.

https://launchpad.net/~satyajit-happy/+archive/ubuntu/themes

Comment: As @OrganicMarble pointed out, supported versions of Lubuntu are supported here. Re. "I would like to get black background and white/bright text on every application including File Manager.", Lubuntu 18.10 not only has gtk applications but also **qt** applications. Both need to be treated separately. What works for gtk apps may not work for qt apps such as the default file manager, pcmanfm-qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Caution: at this stage of Lubuntu's move to LXQt, you can't completely get what you want with the available defaults! But the following suggestions may offer some relief!

Lubuntu 18.10 has *gtk3* applications and *qt* applications and uses *Openbox* as its window manager. These need to be addressed separately.

### Window manager

Lubuntu 18.10 comes with a variety of Openbox themes: some are "dark" with a dark background and light text and window buttons.

To access the graphical user interface, click on the *Menu button > Preferences > LXQt settings > Openbox settings > Theme*. Move your mouse pointer to the pane on the right hand side and scroll up/down to select the theme of your choice. The appearance of the top bar dynamically changes to reflect the theme. I've chosen *Lubuntu Arc*. Clicking *Close* will enforce the selected theme.

[image: Openbox themes]

### gtk3 applications

There some "dark" themes available in the repositories. So you don't really have to resort to ppas or external downloads.

To illustrate, if you run `sudo apt install blackbird-gtk-theme`, that will install a dark theme suitable for both gtk2 and gtk3 applications.

To select *Blackbird* as your choice for gtk2/gtk3 applications, again click on *Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings* and then click on *Appearance*.

In the image below, I've chosen Blackbird for both gtk2 and gtk3 applications.

[image: Selecting your gtk theme]

### qt applications

This is a work-in-progress by the Lubuntu team.

As above, click on *Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings > Appearance*.

You'll notice that *Qt Style* does not offer a dark option at this time. Both *Breeze* and *Fusion* are "light" and *Windows* is probably something you don't want.

[image: Qt Style]

The result of using *Breeze* or *Fusion* is that the area immediately below the application's window decorations and below the main window are light (and not what you want).

### LXQt panel

The same graphical user interface can be used to select from a variety of panel themes. In *Menu > Preferences > Appearance*, click on *LXQt Theme* and make your selection.

[image: Selecting a panel theme]

Here's what a few applications look like:

[image: Some applications]

- QTerminal and Featherpad both have a dark background with light text (other than the area themed by Qt Style).
- PCManFM-Qt is completely light with dark text.
- Mousepad, a gtk3 application, is completely dark with light text.

It's quite possible that someone here knows how to get the appearance you desire but this is as far as I go!