# Linux file manager similar to Windows File Explorer (directory tree + file list)?

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

Which Linux file manager has a UI that mimics Windows File Explorer in a way that it supports a split view with:

- a directory tree on the left, and
- a file list on the right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu 18.10 File Manager: How to view directory tree structure?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120779/lubuntu-18-10-file-manager-how-to-view-directory-tree-structure)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One you can try is `xfe` (X File Explorer).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfe
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Tried a few, but missed this one, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

[Thunar](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/thunar) (the default file manager on Xubuntu) also supports this option under `View` > `Side Pane` > `Tree`

[image]

[image]

Comment: The right side is not good, `xfe` seems much better there.

Comment: @Danijel That is also customizable with `Ctrl+2` or `View` > `View as Detailed List`

Answer (score 9):

## [Nemo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo)

is a fork of *GNOME Files*, formerly *Nautilus*, for the *Cinnamon* desktop which retained the tree view that it had at the time of the fork.

[image: nemo sidebar tree view]

### 1 Installation

- [via *Software*](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nemo)
- on the command line:

  ```
  sudo apt install nemo
  ```

### 2 Configuration

To switch to sidebar tree view:

1. Access *Nemo’s* main menu; you may need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to toggle its visibility.
2. Select *View* → *Sidebar* → *Tree view*.

Answer (score 3):

### [PCManFM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcmanfm/)

I run it in i3 window manager:

[image: PCManFM in i3]

Answer (score 3):

### [Dolphin](https://apps.kde.org/dolphin/)

If you're into KDE or Qt-based software, Dolphin will also do what you want.

It offers various panels in addition to displaying the files in the current folder. One panel, the Files panel (top left in screenshot), shows the files as a hierarchical tree similar to the programs mentioned in the other answers.

It also has a Places panel (bottom left in screenshot) which allows you to add links which go directly to the folders of interest without navigating through the file tree.

[image: Dolphin showing Files and Places panels]

Comment: While this may be correct, how about some explanation oi why Dolphin is a good choice or even a screenshot to show why? As it stands, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I think KDE can still use the old file manager, Konqueror (https://apps.kde.org/en/konqueror), too. It might be more familiar to one used to MS Windows.

Comment: @MarkKirby You're right. Fixed it .

Answer (score 1):

### Double Commander

You can install Double Commander, simply from software GUI for ubuntu 18.04, 20.04:

[image]

You can also install it from terminal too, there are 2 versions, based on the libraries GTK and QT.

First open a terminal with CRTL+ALT+T

if you want to install GTK version run:

```
sudo apt install doublecmd-gtk
```

if you want to install Qt version:

```
sudo apt install doublecmd-qt
```

It is a very powerful file manager where you can customize a kind of dashboard to launch easily your preferred programs.

[image]

or use it with its standard interface

[image]

homepage: https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/

plugins that you can install: https://github.com/doublecmd/doublecmd/wiki/Plugins

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with a link to the software's author?

Comment: homepage added with guideline, wiki, plugins. Hope you find it useful :-)

Comment: Thank you pat!  I appreciate it! (And others may too!) :)