# how to set lxqt dark theme preference for chromium

Tags: lubuntu, themes, chromium, lxqt

Links I've already visited and tried:

- [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120735/lubuntu-18-10-black-theme-black-background-and-white-bright-text-in-every-apps#:~:text=Window%20manager,-Lubuntu%2018.10%20comes&text=To%20access%20the%20graphical%20user,the%20theme%20of%20your%20choice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120735/lubuntu-18-10-black-theme-black-background-and-white-bright-text-in-every-apps#:%7E:text=Window%20manager,-Lubuntu%2018.10%20comes&text=To%20access%20the%20graphical%20user,the%20theme%20of%20your%20choice).
- https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-20-04-fully-dark-theme-background-windows-too/1219

LxQt version: 0.14.1

Ubuntu version:  20.04.3

Some websites have automatic dark themes which are applied automatically based on the system color preference. Changing all the settings to dark in LxQt does not seem to help, and chromium's experimental forced dark mode is not the same thing as what `prefers-color-scheme` does. I would like to know if there is a way to send the value of `prefers-color-scheme` to chromium, or a way to set it inside chromium. The only way I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606960/how-can-i-emulate-prefers-color-scheme-media-query-in-chrome), which is only temporarily emulated.

[this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903) is the related chromium issue, but I'd like a workaround to it that would make chrome do its work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: LXQt themes will impact LXQt & Qt5 windows, but not GTK2 or GTK3 windows, and may not impact *snap* packages either. If you note the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html which is 21.10 as you didn't provide version; adjust for your release if not using 21.10) you can set themes for GTK2 & GTK3 windows too. Chrome has it's own themes & does not use LXQt's theme (likewise chromium which can differ too depending on release/package being used).

Comment: OS andLxqt info added. I also set my GTK3 theme before asking here. It did not change the sites. What I'm looking for is a system value which chrome will use to tell websites whether they should use dark color or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with chromium.

My lubuntu version: 21.10

First you should change GKT theme in lxqt settings:

```
Preferences > LXQT Settings > Appearance > Widget Style
```

Check "Set GTK themes" option and set both GTK-2 & GTK-3 to `Arc-Dark`.
[image: lxqt-settings]

Then in chromium settings search for theme and select "use GTK+" button.

Result:

[image: Chromium dark theme]