# How to change background of nautilus in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I would like to change the background color of the 'explorer' window in Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04. I am using the Ambience theme and am very happy with the look.

I simply want to make the white background a slightly darker color. The answer(s) as [provided for Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465908/how-to-change-background-of-nautilus-in-ubuntu-14-04) does not work for me.

I have tried to edit the following files and locations in a variety of ways with no effect at all:

```
.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
.config/gtk-3.20/gtk.css
.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/apps/nautilus.css
```

After each change I would close all open Nautilus files and then open an 'explorer' window. I would also run `killall nautilus` at times to be sure before I open a new window....

What file do I need to edit so that I could change the background color?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be eaiser to acheive with `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` but in my trail it is also changing and locking the desktop background.

So below is the workaround.

create the file `gtk.css` with below content

```
@import url("/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/gtk.css");
.nautilus-window { background-color: yellow; }
```

place this `gtk.css` file in the blow path.. create the directory's as necessary..
`~/.themes/YELLOW/gtk-3.0/`

choose this Application theme called YELLOW from `gnome-tweaks` or via command line..

[image]

logout and logback in may be necessary..

[image]

Edited Code:

```
@import url("/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/gtk.css");

.nautilus-window { background-color: yellow; }
.nautilus-window .view { background-color: purple; }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @PRATAP. When I select the YELLOW theme in my tweaks GUI, and my Files view is set to folder view, it works! If I set the Files view to "details" a very thin yellow line is presented between the dark dropdown section of the window and the actual folders. My Files (version 3.26.4) background is still white. I suspect I have to change the color of a different variable as well, any ideas?

Comment: Hi, see the edited code in the answer..

Comment: For a list of [colors](https://www.developpez.net/forums/attachments/p345829d1516963382/c-cpp/bibliotheques/gtkp/gtkp-c-cpp/gtkp-2-24-gtk_widget_modify_bg-lutter-contre-changement-climat-informatique/panneau_colore.jpg/)