# Add a Background Image for nautilus in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, lts, nautilus-extensions

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit OS.
Please anyone can tell me how to add background image for nautilus(file browser) and change the background color of nautilus.
Please help me.

Comment: This http://askubuntu.com/questions/65759/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-pattern-in-a-nautilus-window should help you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but gtk-color-scheme value will change color system-wide, I want to change only bg-color of nautilus. Please help me in this issue for **UBUNTU 14.04**

Comment: Take a look at this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/465908/how-to-change-background-of-nautilus-in-ubuntu-14-04 this one should definitely fix it.